# JsonReaderException when trying to deserialize json string

Tags: c#, json, sendgrid

I try to deserialize this json string i get from sendgrid.
I use sendgridplus repository by hakanL: https://github.com/HakanL/sendgridplus-csharp

```
[{"email":"ogsasd@gmail.com","Identification":"934224","timestamp":1387734767,"ip":"83.223.255.137","useragent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B511","category":["ReservationConfirmation"," Online"," Salonkey-86432150"," AppointmentId-132347"," SalonId-223"],"event":"open"}]
```

Here is the method i am using:

```
public static List<EventData> GetEvents(string json)
        {
            // RWM: Deal with v1 and v2 batched Event data.
            if (!json.StartsWith("["))
            {
                json = string.Format("[{0}]", json.Replace("}" + Environment.NewLine + "{", "},{"));
            }

            // RWM: Hack to deal with SendGrid not being able to get their shit together and send well-formed JSON.
            if (!json.EndsWith("]"))
            {
                json += "]";
            }

            _logger.Info("Json returned: " + JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EventData>>(json));

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EventData>>(json);
        }
```

**2013-12-23 10:49:29.0665 INFO**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ]. Path '', line 2, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at itsperfect.ResponseHandler.Mvc.Utils.GetEventData.GetEvents(String json)
   at itsperfect.ResponseHandler.Mvc.Utils.GetEventData.GetEvents(Stream inputStream)
   at itsperfect.ResponseHandler.Mvc.Controllers.EmailController.CatchMailEvent()
```

Comment: Hey Stefan, did you resolved this issue ?

Comment: Yes, but i'm sorry. Cant remember how tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got same issue, looks like response had empty line.

`.TrimEnd()` fixed issue, not bad to ask 'sendgridplus-csharp' add same fix.

```
Dim jsonData As String = sr.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd()
```

also fix 'SendGridCategoryConverter' if you going to serialize your EventData anywhere:

```
//// Left as an exercise to the reader :)

serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
```